# Lazy Loading not working in Entity Framework 6 generated from EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a project that has been using an old version of the Entity Framework for a long time, but I needed to update the database schema (using Database first), so Visual Studio 2013 decided to upgrade me to EF 5 (I have now upgraded to EF 6) when I changed the EDMX file.

In the entity framework as I was previously using it, lazy loading didn't seem to work, but I could call .Load() on the collection or object which would then load it from the database.

e.g, this would work in old EF:

```
public ICollection<CategoryItem> LoadedCategoryItems
{
      get
      {
    CategoryItems.Load();
        return CategoryItems;
      }
}
```

In EF 5/6, CategoryItems will have a count of 0, so lazy loading never seems to work:

```
public ICollection<CategoryItem> LoadedCategoryItems
{
    get
    {
        return CategoryItems;
    }
}
```

This seems to be no way to force load except for doing something like this:

```
database.CategoryItems.Load();
```

Which works around it by preloading it somehow, but I have a many to many relationship in my database which I can't figure out how to preload in this way, so now I'm very stuck and unable to go any further.

As the code for the class is generated by the t4 template created by the edmx file, it is definitely virtual:

```
public virtual HashSet<CategoryItem> CategoryItems { get; set; }
```

The class containing the object is a dynamic proxy, and lazy loading is on.

So I'm not clear why a lazy loading isn't working or how to debug it to find out why it isn't?

How can I figure out what is going on?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Why do you believe lazy loading isnt working? Where are you accessing the CategoryItems? (LazyLoading means it will load the data once you are using it - so for CategoryItems to be loaded you need to call the get of it - are you accessing it somewhere than pls show this part of the code)

Comment: When I try and access it, say in a for loop there are no items in the list. 

Another example is:
    public Image LoadedImage
    {
        get
        {
            return Image;
        }
    }

Here's the code generated by the EDMX:
public virtual Image Image { private get; set; }

When trying to access the image (i.e: use the get) it crashes because it is null.

But if when initialise the application I do this:
database.Images.Load();

It works, which means the lazy loading isn't working.

Comment: You are doing something wrong, I have no problems with LazyLoading in EF 6 when I dont ignore the requirements meant to be set for Lazy Loading to work, which I expect you have them set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx especially you can check the point "The ProxyCreationEnabled option must be set to true."

Comment: I'm definitely aware other people are having it working, the question is why is it not working for me (and seems are others in the same scenario)?

Because the code is generated from an edmx file, it meets all the requirements specified in the link you suggested.

in previous versions at least I could work around the issue.  Now I have a situation where I can't work around the issue and I don't know why lazy loading isn't working. As I said in my post, proxy creation is working & I've re-confirmed that it is on, so I need a way to debug into why the proxy is not doing what it supposed to do.

Comment: If you like to you can send me a test application, where you are facing this problem. I am afraid I cannot help otherwise. Not sure if you know about Include, but with this you could preload the navigation properties, also with a many-to-many relation. For a normal relation include would look like .Include("CategoryItems") - many to many relation would look like .Include("CategoryItems.CategoryGroup.Category.SomeRandom") - with this you can specify a path to the table you want and EF would load all the necessary stuff.

Comment: Ok, turns out the reason for this problem is that the generated code from the EDMX included some private getters.  Now that I have corrected it, this works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons (pre lazy-loading) some of the EDMX generated code used private getters.  This is now not something you can do with lazy loading, so these all had to be changed to public getters